# Sharepoint feature still running after being uninstalled, files removed, IIS restarted

Tags: content-type, feature

I had created a feature that changes the content type of a folder when it is created, which works fine. However, I wanted to make a change to it by adding another folder for it to work in but after updating the code, updating the DLL in the GAC and updating Feature.xml and Elements.xml accordingly and reinstalling, the new code doesn't seem to take.

In fact, even after uninstalling it, removing the DLL from the GAC and removing the folder from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\, it is not showing up in Site Features, but is still running. Am I missing something? It seems like the changes I made to the feature and the fact that I removed it had no effect on its behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading SharePoint Manager 2007 (http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438) to inspect the object model. You should be able to see if the Event Receivers are still active on the list as well as inspect any features that are installed/activated.

Comment: I doubt my manager will want to install anything else on our already overcrowded dev server, but thanks again MB!

Comment: It runs without installation, standalone app, so you can have a peek then delete it straight afterwards.

Comment: Hey James - I installed Sharepoint Manager to take a look at the events.  Where do I go to look at the events? :P

Comment: If you drill down into your site collection, then your Web, and then Lists. Within this item, look for your list/document library. Underneath that item, there is an Event Receivers tree item. If there are any items under there, you will be able to see all the information about that receiver.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked to see if the ddl's are delpoyed to the bin catalog in SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

Did you remove the information from web.config file. And also you need to delete it from assembly folder.

Hope the information helps

Thanks & Regards,
Chandra Shekhar